# lsblk -f detects my hard disk filesystem as vfat and not fat32

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I need to list the hard disk with the file system but it is not returning the right one so I was wondering, am I maybe not using the right command or is there something else I missed?

[sdb1 is returned as a vfat filesystem but i am 100% sure it is fat32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG7y5.png)

I tried a few other commands, but either they return way too much text or I would need to install them as they do not come with the base xubuntu that I downloaded.

Also while I would very much like if someone can help me find the command i need, I am mostly intrigued by the fact that it detects fat32 as vfat and how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading some stuff online i found out that most commands do not specify if a file system is fat or fat32. For this level of detail this command should be used

```
sudo file -s /dev/sda1
```

Example, on a USB key:

> /dev/sdc: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "MSWIN4.1",
>   sectors/cluster 32, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads
>   255, sectors 15794176 (volumes > 32 MB) , **FAT (32 bit)**, sectors/FAT
>   3856, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x4c437f55, unlabeled

Hope it helps.

Comment: This command works as well: sudo minfo -i /dev/sdb1 | grep 'disk type'